# Angular Async Validator not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am tying to implement custom async validator in angular. But it does not seem to be working.
There are no errors in the console.

validator `shouldBeUnique` is an async validator which is not working
validator  `cannotContainSpace` is non async custom validator which works just fine. 
I am not able to figure out what went wrong.

View:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input 
        formControlName="username"
            id="username" 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control">

            <div *ngIf="username.errors.cannotContainSpace" class="alert alert-danger">Can not have space</div>
            <div *ngIf="username.errors.shouldBeUnique" class="alert alert-danger">shouldBeUniquee</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input 
        formControlName="password"
            id="password" 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

**Component:**

```
export class SignupFormComponent {
  form = new FormGroup(
    {
      username: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,
      UsernameValidators.cannotContainSpace, UsernameValidators.shouldBeUnique
      ]),
      password: new FormControl('', Validators.required),


    });

  get username() {
    console.log(this.form.get('username').errors.shouldBeUnique);
    return this.form.get('username');
  }
}
```

**username.validator.ts**

```
export class UsernameValidators {
    static cannotContainSpace(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        if ((control.value as string).indexOf(' ') != -1) {
            console.log('noo');
            return { cannotContainSpace: true };
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    static shouldBeUnique(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => { 
                if (control.value === 'arbaaz')
                    resolve( { shouldBeUnique: false });
                    else                  
                    resolve(null); 
            }, 2000);
        });
    } 
}
```

Comment: This question saved a lot of time for me.
Very well written code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async validators should be placed as the third argument:

```
username: new FormControl('', 
          [Validators.required, UsernameValidators.cannotContainSpace],
          [UsernameValidators.shouldBeUnique]),
```

Comment: Now I am getting `Cannot read property 'cannotContainSpace' of null`

Comment: @Arbaaz `username.errors?.cannotContainSpace` Also maybe you meant `resolve( { shouldBeUnique: true });`

Comment: @yurzui The tutorial video which implemented this code did not have to write ? and it still worked fine. I wonder why.

Comment: @yurzui I wish I could. It's Mosh Hamedani's Complete Angular Tutorial on Udemy.
I have taken a screenshot for you though. 
https://snag.gy/tY6wzm.jpg

Comment: @Arbaaz In that tutorial author checks `invalid` property first https://monosnap.com/file/KNiQ7XxZVn07dAPlXQ1YUnjIVWiV5c So if `username.invalid` then it for sure has errors.

Comment: Great, yurzui takes care of problems while I'm gone :D But great, @Arbaaz glad this sorted itself out! :)

Comment: @yurzui What if we don't want second validation like Validators.required? I only want my asyn validation and not any other validation.

Comment: @AJT_82 Can we have async validtion without second validation. Thanks