# How can we set sync validation null when adding async angular validation?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation, angular-formbuilder

I am trying to create a control with async validation and I don't want sync validation:

Creating form using formBuilder.

```
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({ 
    someControl: new FormControl(
        "",
        null,
        [this.valueUnique.bind(this)]
      )})
```

If I keep sync validation parameter as Validators.required then I get no error.

**Error:**

> ERROR Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.
>       at toObservable (forms.js:603)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at FormControl.asyncValidator (forms.js:591)
>       at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl._runAsyncValidator
>   (forms.js:2535)
>       at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity
>   (forms.js:2508)
>       at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl._updateTreeValidity
>   (forms.js:2523)
>       at forms.js:2522
>       at forms.js:3309
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at FormGroup.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroup._forEachChild
>   (forms.js:3309)

Validator function:

```
 /**
   * Validator to checking existance/uniqueness
   * of entered value
   * @param control
   */
   valueIsUnique(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors|null> | null {
    if (control && (control.value !== null && control.value !== undefined)) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.service.checkValueExists(control.value).subscribe(res => {
         {
            if (res && res['data']) {
              resolve({
                unique: true
              });
            }
              else {
                resolve(null);
            }
           }
          },
            err=>
          {
            resolve(null);
          });
    });
  }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `this.valueUnique.bind(this)` is returning an `Observable` or `Promise`? Because hat is what the error says, your binding to the function `valueUnique` is not returning this type.

Comment: @SamVloeberghs thanks, yes my async validator returning promise. I have updated question.
Also added similar post yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375700/how-to-add-async-validation-without-adding-any-other-validators

If I add sync validation = Validators.required then error does not come.

Comment: your if should be inside the return new Promise. You have a potential case here that you are not return a promise.

Comment: @SamVloeberghs Ok thanks. Let me check and I will update you.

Comment: @SamVloeberghs How can I return promise in that If conditione it is outside new promise?

Comment: Thankyou So so much @SamVloeberghs. It worked. You are a savior!

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old but maybe my answer could be useful.

I tried this way and it worked.

```
archivos: [null, [] , mimeType],
```

It only worked if i put the square brackets for sync validators and don´t put them for async validator.

Comment: Hi @javier Thanks for posting this. I will try this solution next time.